# SQL Select Group with a Common Value

Tags: sqlite

I'm scratching my head on how to do this select.

Table (GroupID, Participants)
g1, A
g1, B
g2, A
g2, C
g3, A
g3, B
g3, C
g4, A
g4, B
g4, C
g4, D

I want to select the GroupID that only A, B, C share (in this case, that would be g3). Notice that I do NOT want g4, as I want the GroupID that ONLY A, B, C is in. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select `groupid`s that have at least 3 different `participants`

```
select groupid
from your_table
group by groupid
having count(distinct participants) >= 3
```

To make this explicit to `A,B,C` you can do

```
select groupid
from your_table
where participants in ('A','B','C')
group by groupid
having count(distinct participants) = 3
```

And if you do not want any other participants then do

```
select groupid
from your_table
group by groupid
having sum(participants = 'A') > 0
and sum(participants = 'B') > 0
and sum(participants = 'C') > 0
and sum(participants not in ('A','B','C')) = 0
```

or

```
select groupid
from your_table
group by groupid
having sum(participants not in ('A','B','C')) = 0
and count(distinct participants) = 3
```

Comment: The groupID will be unique based on the participants who are in the group. For example, g1 is only for A, B. If A, B, C is selected as participants, that creates another group. The number of participants also can vary.

Comment: That last version might be what I'm looking for. Performance-wise, is this the best way?

Comment: I'm trying the third block but its not recognizing the syntax for a condition inside of a sum function.

Comment: Nevermind. I was trying to confirm the syntax in TSQL. In SQLite it works. For future reference, how would one do this in TSQL as well, since the sum function doesn't take conditions?

Comment: In TSQL instead of `sum(participants = 'B')` use a case: `sum(case when participants = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)`